# Using WHERE function with $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am currently importing data using the $_POST function. I want to use the imported value as the selected column. Currenlty my code looks like this:

```
$value = $_POST["name"]

$sql = "SELECT question_id, question FROM Question WHERE question_id= $value";
```

I am currently getting an error when I call my php script using JQuery. Is this section of the code the potential source?

This is the JQuery code I'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('#show').load('/php/getQuestion.php'), { name: $("#txtname").val()}
        });

    });
</script>
```

Txtname is `<strong>Name:</strong><input type = "text" id = "txtname">`

There error is

```
f.send(a.hasContent&&a.data||null),b=function(c,e){var h,i,j;if(b&&(e||4===f.readyState))if(delete Yc[g],b=void 0,f.onreadystatechange=n.noop,e)4!==f.readyState&&f.abort();else{j={},h=f.status,"string"==typeof f.responseText&&(j.text=f.responseText);try{i=f.statusText}catch(k){i=""}h||!a.isLocal||a.crossDomain?1223===h&&(h=204):h=j.text?200:404}j&&d(h,i,j,f.getAllResponseHeaders())},a.async?4===f.readyState?setTimeout(b):f.onreadystatechange=Yc[g]=b:b()},abort:function(){b&&b(void 0,!0)}}}});function $c(){try{return new a.XMLHttpRequest}catch(b){}}function _c(){try{return new a.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(b){}}n.ajaxSetup({accepts:{script:"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"},contents:{script:/(?:java|ecma)script/},converters:{"text script":function(a){return n.globalEval(a),a}}}),n.ajaxPrefilter("script",function(a){void 0===a.cache&&(a.cache=!1),a.crossDomain&&(a.type="GET",a.global=!1)}),n.ajaxTransport("script",function(a){if(a.crossDomain){var b,c=z.head||n("head")[0]||z.documentElement;return{send:function(d,e){b=z.createElement("script"),b.async=!0,a.scriptCharset&&(b.charset=a.scriptCharset),b.src=a.url,b.onload=b.onreadystatechange=function(a,c){(c||!b.readyState||/loaded|complete/.test(b.readyState))&&(b.onload=b.onreadystatechange=null,b.parentNode&&b.parentNode.removeChild(b),b=null,c||e(200,"success"))},c.insertBefore(b,c.firstChild)},abort:function(){b&&b.onload(void 0,!0)}}}});var ad=[],bd=/(=)\?(?=&|$)|\?\?/;n.ajaxSetup({jsonp:"callback",jsonpCallback:function(){var a=ad.pop()||n.expando+"_"+wc++;return this[a]=!0,a}}),n.ajaxPrefilter("json jsonp",function(b,c,d){var e,f,g,h=b.jsonp!==!1&&(bd.test(b.url)?"url":"string"==typeof b.data&&!(b.contentType||"").indexOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")&&bd.test(b.data)&&"data");return h||"jsonp"===b.dataTypes[0]?(e=b.jsonpCallback=n.isFunction(b.jsonpCallback)?b.jsonpCallback():b.jsonpCallback,h?b[h]=b[h].replace(bd,"$1"+e):b.jsonp!==!1&&(b.url+=(xc.test(b.url)?"&":"?")+b.jsonp+"="+e),b.converters["script json"]=function(){return g||n.error(e+" was not called"),g[0]},b.dataTypes[0]="json",f=a[e],a[e]=function(){g=arguments},d.always(function(){a[e]=f,b[e]&&(b.jsonpCallback=c.jsonpCallback,ad.push(e)),g&&n.isFunction(f)&&f(g[0]),g=f=void 0}),"script"):void 0}),n.parseHTML=function(a,b,c){if(!a||"string"!=typeof a)return null;"boolean"==typeof b&&(c=b,b=!1),b=b||z;var d=v.exec(a),e=!c&&[];return d?[b.createElement(d[1])]:(d=n.buildFragment([a],b,e),e&&e.length&&n(e).remove(),n.merge([],d.childNodes))};var cd=n.fn.load;n.fn.load=function(a,b,c){if("string"!=typeof a&&cd)return cd.apply(this,arguments);var d,e,f,g=this,h=a.indexOf(" ");return h>=0&&(d=a.slice(h,a.length),a=a.slice(0,h)),n.isFunction(b)?(c=b,b=void 0):b&&"object"==typeof b&&(f="POST"),g.length>0&&n.ajax({url:a,type:f,dataType:"html",data:b}).done(function(a){e=arguments,g.html(d?n("<div>").append(n.parseHTML(a)).find(d):a)}).complete(c&&function(a,b){g.each(c,e||[a.responseText,b,a])}),this},n.expr.filters.animated=function(a){return n.grep(n.timers,function(b){return a===b.elem}).length};var dd=a.document.documentElement;function ed(a){return n.isWindow(a)?a:9===a.nodeType?a.defaultView||a.parentWindow:!1}n.offset={setOffset:function(a,b,c){var d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k=n.css(a,"position"),l=n(a),m={};"static"===k&&(a.style.position="relative"),h=l.offset(),f=n.css(a,"top"),i=n.css(a,"left"),j=("absolute"===k||"fixed"===k)&&n.inArray("auto",[f,i])>-1,j?(d=l.position(),g=d.top,e=d.left):(g=parseFloat(f)||0,e=parseFloat(i)||0),n.isFunction(b)&&(b=b.call(a,c,h)),null!=b.top&&(m.top=b.top-h.top+g),null!=b.left&&(m.left=b.left-h.left+e),"using"in b?b.using.call(a,m):l.css(m)}},n.fn.extend({offset:function(a){if(arguments.length)return void 0===a?this:this.each(function(b){n.offset.setOffset(this,a,b)});var b,c,d={top:0,left:0},e=this[0],f=e&&e.ownerDocument;if(f)return b=f.documentElement,n.contains(b,e)?(typeof e.getBoundingClientRect!==L&&(d=e.getBoundingClientRect()),c=ed(f),{top:d.top+(c.pageYOffset||b.scrollTop)-(b.clientTop||0),left:d.left+(c.pageXOffset||b.scrollLeft)-(b.clientLeft||0)}):d},position:function(){if(this[0]){var a,b,c={top:0,left:0},d=this[0];return"fixed"===n.css(d,"position")?b=d.getBoundingClientRect():(a=this.offsetParent(),b=this.offset(),n.nodeName(a[0],"html")||(c=a.offset()),c.top+=n.css(a[0],"borderTopWidth",!0),c.left+=n.css(a[0],"borderLeftWidth",!0)),{top:b.top-c.top-n.css(d,"marginTop",!0),left:b.left-c.left-n.css(d,"marginLeft",!0)}}},offsetParent:function(){return this.map(function(){var a=this.offsetParent||dd;while(a&&!n.nodeName(a,"html")&&"static"===n.css(a,"position"))a=a.offsetParent;return a||dd})}}),n.each({scrollLeft:"pageXOffset",scrollTop:"pageYOffset"},function(a,b){var c=/Y/.test(b);n.fn[a]=function(d){return W(this,function(a,d,e){var f=ed(a);return void 0===e?f?b in f?f[b]:f.document.documentElement[d]:a[d]:void(f?f.scrollTo(c?n(f).scrollLeft():e,c?e:n(f).scrollTop()):a[d]=e)},a,d,arguments.length,null)}}),n.each(["top","left"],function(a,b){n.cssHooks[b]=Mb(l.pixelPosition,function(a,c){return c?(c=Kb(a,b),Ib.test(c)?n(a).position()[b]+"px":c):void 0})}),n.each({Height:"height",Width:"width"},function(a,b){n.each({padding:"inner"+a,content:b,"":"outer"+a},function(c,d){n.fn[d]=function(d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return W(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:9===b.nodeType?(e=b.documentElement,Math.max(b.body["scroll"+a],e["scroll"+a],b.body["offset"+a],e["offset"+a],e["client"+a])):void 0===d?n.css(b,c,g):n.style(b,c,d,g)},b,f?d:void 0,f,null)}})}),n.fn.size=function(){return this.length},n.fn.andSelf=n.fn.addBack,"function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&define("jquery",[],function(){return n});var fd=a.jQuery,gd=a.$;return n.noConflict=function(b){return a.$===n&&(a.$=gd),b&&a.jQuery===n&&(a.jQuery=fd),n},typeof b===L&&(a.jQuery=a.$=n),n});
```

Comment: Is your jQuery code post the value of name??

Comment: I think problem is quote. Use `'`(single) quote to your variable. $sql = "SELECT question_id, question FROM Question WHERE question_id= '".$value."'"; ......

Comment: check the field type of question_id column, i think it should be `question_id= '$value'`

Comment: What is the error message? You are open to sql injection, you should sanitize the posted data.

Comment: `$_POST` is not a function and same goes for `WHERE`.

Comment: I added the jQuery code I'm using

Comment: @user1234231, What kind of error you fetch??

Comment: your jquery load syntax is wrong, how come click method with hold a function with some random code?

Comment: A 500 Internal Service Error. Put it in the question

Comment: [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) closing is not correct and it takes second parameter as arguments, but you are closing it before passing your params. Otherwise, your query should work, which seems error less. Only a semicolon missed after `$value = $_POST["name"]`

Comment: @RohanKumar How can I close it correctly?

Comment: @user1234231 try my answer added below.

Comment: @user1234231 you have modified the question once you get other error right ?

Comment: @Chintan7027 I added more information to help people understand my issue better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) closing is not correct and it takes second parameter as arguments, but you are closing it before passing your params

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#show').load('/php/getQuestion.php',
          { name: $("#txtname").val()} );
               // ---------------------^ closing parenthesis of load()
    });
});
```

In PHP you have missed semicolon after `$value = $_POST["name"]`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT question_id, question FROM Question WHERE question_id = ".$value;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all wrap your argument as string

```
$value = $_POST["name"];
$sql = "SELECT `question_id`, `question` FROM Question WHERE `question_id` like '%$value%'";
```

or

```
$value = (integer)$_POST["name"];
$sql = "SELECT `question_id`, `question` FROM Question WHERE `question_id` = {$value}";
```

Comment: Why wrap?? If the `question _id` is **int** then it will not necessary to wrap. Why use `like`?

Comment: Yes agree integere value need to wrap, but he don'e mention anything that's why using anything from $_POST is not safe

Comment: If sure that id is integer than cast the $_POST value to integer at either PHP level or mysql level

Comment: So you may ask the OP about your clearance, no need to post it as answer which is actually not the valid answer.

Comment: I wanted an integer, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: This will definitely give syntax error as there is missing semicolon after `$value = $_POST["name"]`

Comment: @RohanKumar You can simply edit the answer if you found anything wrong, i will approve that.

Comment: It was an error, and you should correct it. SO users can comment in that case.